# C# MVC save View as png

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memorystream, html-rendering

i have problem with png HTML renderer, 
i am trying to send png of View to email, but on email i get 0B .png
PS: Ticket.pdf is ok

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(RenderRazorViewToString("TicketTemplateBig", model), PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
            pdf.Save(ms, false);

            /////////////////
            //Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(1024), Convert.ToInt32(1024), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //Image image = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WinForms.HtmlRender.RenderToImage(RenderRazorViewToString("TicketTemplateBig", model));

                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\logo.png");
                bitmap.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Png);


                /////////////////
                await ms.FlushAsync();
                await ms2.FlushAsync();
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, string.Format("Ticket.pdf"), "application/pdf"));
                streams.Add(ms);
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms2, string.Format("logo.png"), "application/png"));
                streams.Add(ms2);
                await client.SendMailAsync(mm);
            }
        }
```

Comment: try changing application/Png to application/img or application/png

Comment: as I see it you are not writing to the memory stream ms2.

Comment: Have you verified that this code can actually create a valid .ping file?  I'd try writing to a `FileStream` pointed to a local .png file, and making sure you can open it first.  That will let you know if the problem is with the rendering, the stream, or the email.

Comment: @BradleyUffner i tried , and its sending 0B png too

and i added flush to ms2 and still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem : stream was on last position

result  :  ms2.Position = 0;

```
           using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(RenderRazorViewToString("TicketTemplateBig", model), PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
            pdf.Save(ms, false);

            using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Image image = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WinForms.HtmlRender.RenderToImage(RenderRazorViewToString("TicketTemplateBig", model));
                image.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Png);
                ms2.Position = 0;
                await ms.FlushAsync();
                await ms2.FlushAsync();
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, string.Format("Ticket.pdf"), "application/pdf"));
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms2, string.Format("Ticket.png"), "application/png"));
                await client.SendMailAsync(mm);
            }
        }
```

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send the mail before having effectively written to `ms2`.

you need to do flush the `ms2` stream buffer before adding it to `mm` . (as you did for `ms`, that's why the pdf part was handled correctly)

(Also, minor typo :  "application/png" instead of "application/Png", probably not an issue)